# Trying to make a boostrap div with class row thesame width with the row of the container

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have container with a width auto and I have a div of class=row placed into a div container but my issue is that the div with class row is not having the same width with that of the div with class container. This is my attempt

```
<div style="background-color:#98FB98; height:350px; width:auto;" class="row">
        <div style="padding:15px;" class="col-md-6">
            Contents here
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Logo here
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a plunk I have made.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/griWXBoxozvPIMlf38RB?p=preview
```

Please how can I make the div and hr tags have the same width with the div of class container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one: remove padding for `.container`, you have padding-right there.
The second one: You use div with class `.col-lg-12` - it has default left and right paddings so it should be inside some `.row` element if you don't want to have gaps on the left and right side ;)

You should read more about bootstrap grid, you use it in incorrect way, this green box should be inside some `.row` div, not inside `.col-lg-12` an it shouldn't has class `.row`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin-left : 250 px and margin-right: 250 px from container class and it will work fine

```
.container {
      width: auto;
      height: 500px;
      max-height: 500px !important;
      padding-left: 0px;
      position: relative;
    }
```

Link to fixed plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/KfxAnGfaeLOIOWvqxWkY?p=preview

Comment: Can not see any difference. The div with green background width is not thesame with the parent div

Comment: Did you check the link?

Comment: Yes I did. The width of the div with green background is not the same with the width of the div with black background